# Convergence in distribution of infinitely divisible random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Any hints or solutions would be appreciated

[image]

I'm stuck on this question.  My idea for part a is to first show that this convergence holds for a fixed subdivision into $n$ parts. We know the sequence $X_m$ is tight because it converges in distribution to a random variable, but other than that, I'm not sure how to use the tightness to show that $X_{\infty}$ also breaks up into the sum of $n$ iid random variables.

For part b, my guess is that because $X$ has support $[-1,1]$, the support of $X_i^{(n)}$ will be $[-1/n,1/n]$ but I'm not sure how to use that to get a contradiction.

Source: Old Qual Problem https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Fall_2012/20123_507a.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a) the idea is to fix $n$ and prove that if $X_m = X_m^{(1)} + \dots + X_m^{(n)}$ where $X_m^{(i)}$ are iid then each of the sequences $(X_m^{(i)})_{m \geq 1}$ is tight and hence there is a subsequence along which each of the $X_m^{(i)}$ converge in distribution. That is we want to check that 
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P} \big(|X_m^{(i)}|>k \big) = 0
$$
So we notice that 
$$\mathbb{P}\big(X_m^{(i)}>k\big)^n=\mathbb{P}\big(X_m^{(1)}>k, \dots X_m^{(n)} > k \big)\leq \mathbb{P}(X_m>k)$$
and similar bounds hold for $\mathbb{P}\big(X_m^{(i)}< -k\big)$. Using the fact that the sequence $X_m$ is tight we get that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(|X_m| > k) = 0$ and so combining with the above bounds we get that the desired condition holds and the sequence $X_m^{(i)}$ is tight. Hence we can find a subsequence $m_k$ such that for each $i$, $X_{m_k}^{(i)} \to X^{(i)}$ in distribution. It is then easy to see that the $X^{(i)}$ are i.i.d. and that $X = X^{(1)} + \dots + X^{(n)}$.

For (b) and (c) you can use the fact that a non-degenerate, infinitely divisible random variable cannot be bounded. Indeed if $X$ is infinitely divisible and $|X| < K$ then $X = X_1 + \dots X_n$ with the $X_i$ iid implies 
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(X_1>\frac{K}{n}\Big)^n=\mathbb{P}\left (X_1>\frac{K}{n},\dots,X_n>\frac{K}{n}\right)\leq \mathbb{P}(X>K)=0$$
and similarly $\mathbb{P} \big (X_1 < - \frac{K}{n} \big) = 0$. As a result $|X_i| < \frac{K}{n}$ for each $i$ so $Var(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i) \leq \frac{C}{n}$ for some constant $C$. But $n$ was arbitrary so by sending $n \to \infty$ we're done.

Comment: Thanks! most of the solution made sense but I'm still trying to understand the last lines. why do we have var(X)≤C/n?

Comment: It's enough to see that $Var(X_i) \leq C_i / n^2$ for some constant $C_i$. To see this simply note that $Var(X_i) = \mathbb{E}[X_i^2] - \mathbb{E}[X_i]^2 \leq \mathbb{E}[K^2 / n^2] + \mathbb{E}[K/n]^2 = 2K^2 / n^2$.